# everypage top identify and place text in latex file automatically

Tags: automation, everypage

I would like to add the top of text mark in the latex file automatically (everypage). My MWE is :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{everypage}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sc@ep@init}{%
  \let\sc@op@saved\@outputpage
  \def\@outputpage{%
    XXX\sc@op@preamble
    YYY\sc@op@saved
    \sc@op@postamble}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Article title here}

\section{Introduction}

Separation logic is a well-known with aaa pointers stemming from BI logic. Such programs have specific errors to be detected and separation logic is used as an assertion language for Hoare-like proof systems that are dedicated to verify programs manipulating heaps. Any procedure mechanizing the proof search requires subroutines that check the satisfiability or the validity of formulae (more precisely entailment) from the assertion language. That is why, characterizing the computational complexity of separation logic and its fragments and designing optimal decision procedures remain essential tasks. Separation logic contains a structural separating connective and its adjoint (the separating implication, also known as the magic wand).

The main concern of the paper is to study a non-trivial fragment of first-order separation logic with one record field as far as expressive power, decidability and complexity are concerned. Herein, the models of separation logic are pairsmade of a variable valuation (store) and a partial function with finite domain (heap), also known as memory states. 

Separation logic is a well-known logic for analysing programs with pointers stemming from BI logic. Such programs have specific errors to be detected and separation logic is used as an assertion language for Hoare-like proof systems that are dedicated to verify programs manipulating heaps. Any procedure mechanizing the proof search requires subroutines that check the satisfiability or the validity of formul{\ae} (more precisely entailment) from the assertion language. That is why, characterizing the computational complexity of separation logic and its fragments and designing optimal decision procedures remain essential tasks. Separation logic contains a structural separating connective and its adjoint (the separating implication, also known as the magic wand).  Concise and modular proofs can be derived using these connectives, since they can express properties such as non-aliasing.

The main concern of the paper is to study a non-trivial fragment of first-order separation logic with one record field as far as expressive power, decidability and complexity are concerned. Herein, the models of separation logic are pairs made of a variable valuation (store) and a partial function with finite domain (heap), also known as memory states.

Separation logic is a well-known logic for analysing programs with pointers stemming from BI logic. Such programs have specific errors to be detected and separation logic is used as an assertion language for iability or the validity of formul{\ae} (more precisely entailment) from the assertion language. That is why, characterizing the computational complexity of separation logic and its fragments and designing optimal decision procedures remain essential tasks. Separation logic contains a structural separating connective and its adjoint (the separating implication, also known as the magic wand).  Concise and modular proofs can be derived using these connectives, since they can express properties such as non-aliasing.

The main concern of the paper is to study a non-trivial fragment of first-order separation logic with one record field as far as expressive power, decidability and complexity are concerned. Herein, the models of separation logic are pairs made of a variable valuation (store) and a partial function with finite domain (heap), also known as memory states.  Separation logic is a well-known logic for analysing programs with pointers stemming from BI logic. Such programs have specific errors to be detected and separation logic is used as an assertion language for Hoare-like proof systems that are dedicated to verify programs manipulating heaps. Any procedure mechanizing the proof search requires subroutines that check the satisfiability or the validity of formul{\ae} (more precisely entailment) from the assertion language. That is why, characterizing the computational complexity of separation logic and its fragments and designing optimal decision procedures remain essential tasks. Separation logic contains a structural separating connective and its adjoint (the separating implication, also known as the magic wand).  Concise and modular proofs can be derived using these connectives, since they can express properties such asnon-aliasing.

The main concern of the paper is to study a non-trivial fragment of first-order separation logic with one record field as far as expressive power, decidability and complexity are concerned. Herein, the models of separation logic are pairs made of a variable valuation (store) and a partial function with finite domain (heap), also known as memory states. 

Separation logic is a well-known logic for analysing programs with pointers stemming from BI logic. Such programs have specific errors to be detected and separation logic is used as an assertion language for Hoare-like proof systems that are dedicated to verify programs manipulating heaps. Any procedure mechanizing the proof search requires subroutines that check the satisfiability or the validity of formul{\ae} (more precisely entailment) from the assertion lan,,,,,,guage. asdfasdfThat is why, characterizing the computational complexity of separation logic and its fragments and designing optimal decision procedures remain essential tasks. Separation logic contains a structural separating connective and its adjoint (the separating implication, also known as the magic wand). Concise and modular proofs can be derived using these connectives, since they can express properties such as non-aliasing.  The main concern of the paper is to study a non-trivial fragment of first-order separation logic with one record fieldas far as expressive power, decidability and complexity are concerned. Herein, the models of separation logic are pairs made of a variable valuation (store) and a partial function with finite domain (heap), also known as memory states.

Separation logic is a well-known logic for analysing programs with pointers stemming from BI logic. Such programs have specific errors to be detected and separation logic is used as an assertion language for Hoare-like proof systems that are dedicated to verify programs manipulating heaps. Any procedure mechanizing the proof search requires subroutines that check the satisfiability or the validity of formul{\ae} (more precisely entailment) from the assertion language. That is why, characterizing the computational complexity of separation logic and its fragments and designing optimal decision procedures remain essential tasks. Separation logic contains a structural separating connective and its adjoint (the separating implication, also known as the magic wand). Concise and modular proofs can be derived using these connectives, since they can express properties such as non-aliasing.

\end{document}
```

So, each and every page what text is coming i would like to add some marker text like {%startpage} in the LaTeX file. How to achieve this...

Comment: There is no option in LaTeX? Any possibilities or idea will be greatly appreciate.